# Multiple IF(AND statements combination troubleshooting

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas

I made a spreadsheet that calculates insurance rates based on employer contribution % towards the employee and dependent.  The entire formula works perfectly except the combination of 100% employer contribution for employee and >0.1%, which is the last section of the formula below.  I attempted to cover all possible combinations:

```
Employer Contribution
Employee    Dependent
0%             0%
100%           0%
100%          100%
1%-99%         0%
1%-99%        1-99%
100%          1-99% - This combination produces a "FALSE" in the formula below
```

Here is how the spreadsheet is laid out:

```
Employer Contribution
Employee:100% (Cell A1) Dependent:0% (Cell A2)- Enter any percentage for each


               Below are hard keyed numbers
   (Cell A4) (Cell B4) (Cell C4)(Cell D4)(Cell E4)
    Name       Employee  Spouse  Children  Total    Name       Employer Employee    Total

    Johnson     $200      $200     $100     $500   Johnson     POPULATED BASED ON THE FORMULA
```

Here is the formula:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0%,A2=0%),0,
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2=0%),B4,
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2=100%),E4,
IF(AND(A1>1%,A1<=99%,A2=0%),A1*B4,
IF(AND(A1>1%,A1<=99%,A2>1%,A2<=99%),(SUM(C4:D4)*A2)+(A1*B4,
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2>1%,A2<=99%),(SUM(C4:D4)*A2)+(A1*B4))))))))
```

I am looking to troubleshoot why the last combination does not work.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Divide et empera. There is no reason to have one huge statement, break it into smaller parts and it will be much easier to grasp. When it works, you can merge it back into one statement. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: @kurdy - I split out the last part of the formula and it gives me the correct answer, but I am trying to figure out why when linked with the rest of the formula, it doesn't produce the right answer.

Comment: Where are you covering condition `1%-99%         0%` which you have shown in first table?

Comment: @shrivallabhaRedij - I was looking at that after I posted this question, but if put 1-99% in employee and 0% in dependent, it still calculates the right answer.

Comment: Your inner most `IF` is of the form `IF(<test>,<if-true>,<nothing>)`, which will return `FALSE` when `<test>` is `FALSE`. You need to add an expression in place of `<nothing>`. As an aside, two cases `AND(A1>0.1%,A1<100%,A2=0)` and `AND(A1>0.1%,A1<100%,A2=100%)` are not covered by the logic of your formula.

Comment: @xidgel - thank you for the reply.  What IF statement are you referring to that needs an expression?

Comment: The inner-most one — `IF(AND(A1=100%,A2>1%,A2<=99%)...`

Comment: @xidgel - Thank you for the reply.  The formula doesn't work across multiple sheets, but as soon as I moved the contribution % to the calculation sheet, it works fine.  Why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to look and fix.

- The first AND condition remains open and isn't closed properly.
- 0.1% reduces the value to 0.001. So it should be either 1% or 0.01.
- 4th condition, if true, doesn't have expression to evaluate.
- 6th condition, if true, will not calculate correctly as in this condition as per your formula you are multiplying by cell A4 (`A1*A4`) which just won't work as A4 cell has text value i.e. Johnson.

You need to address these conditions. Here's my suggestion where I have written `A1*B4` for last condition:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0%,A2=0%),0,
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2=0%),B4,
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2=100%),E4,
IF(AND(A1>=1%,A1<=99%,A2=0%),"CASE 4",
IF(AND(A1>=1%,A1<=99%,A2>=1%,A2<=99%),(SUM(C4:D4)*A2)+(B4*A1),
IF(AND(A1=100%,A2>=1%,A2<=99%),(SUM(C4:D4)*A2)+(A1*B4),"UNDEFINED CASE!"))))))
```

**EDIT** - I am not sure how you are applying it. Posting a link to the file. [See Here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5wvyib9oyvpjho/stackoverflow_46933654.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I edited the formula above to show the edits you made.  I am still receiving a FALSE from the formula when I put 100% in A1 and anything greater than 1% in A2 (last line in formula).  I didn't add anything where you wrote "undefined case" because I thought the other IF(AND's would cover every other combination so I am confused to why I am receiving false?

Comment: I am not sure how you are implementing above formula. I have posted a sample file. Take a look and let me know.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but as soon as I input the formula into my actual workbook, it does not work.  Am I able to post it?

Comment: This site doesn't allow a direct upload but you can upload file and share link here. I can take a look.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Hery0502 Load file on a file sharing site. One such site is dropbox.com (you need to register on this site).